# Convert session variable list of GUIDs to list of strings

Tags: c#, list

I have a session variable that's set to a list of GUIDs. I need to convert that list of GUIDs into strings. I know very very little about session variables and have limited experience with C#, hence the probably stupid solutions I've tried below:

`Session["OtherProgramIDs"]` is of type `object{System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Guid?>}`

Doesn't work, gives me "InvalidCastException",

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]]' to
>   type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'":

```
var otherProgramList = (List<string>)Session["OtherProgramIDs"];
```

Doesn't work, this gives me a message that says "object does not contain a definition for Select and no extension method Select accepting a first argument of type object could be found":

```
var otherProgramList = Session["OtherProgramIDs"].Select(x => (string)x).ToList();
```

This gives me the same message as above:

```
var otherProgramList = Session["OtherProgramIDs"].Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Do I need to loop through it using .ToString() and then adding to the otherProgramList or something?

**EDIT**

I've added the error messages above. Have also tried this suggestion from the comments and receive the same highlighted error above about System.Collections.Generic.List yada yada yada.

`var otherProgramList = ((IEnumerable<Guid>)Session["OtherProgramIDs"]).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();`

FYI - it is ok that this GUID is nullable, there are other constraints at play that make this so.

Comment: `((IEnumerable<Guid>)Session["OtherProgramIDs"]).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()`

Comment: Define "Doesn't work". What exception are you getting?

Comment: When you debug, of what type is the value returned by `Session["OtherProgramIDs]`? (I don't mean `object` - the return type of the indexer, I mean the real type of the returned object). And what does "Doesn't work" mean? we could help you 200% faster if you tell us the error messages. I bet your second approach works if you use `x.ToString()` instead of `(string)x`. Because a `GUID` is cannot be _cast_ to a `string`, but has a `ToString()` method.

Comment: A Guid isn't a string so you can't cast it to a string. Use `ToString()` to generate a string from the GUID. Check the docs for the format specifiers that work with `Guid.ToString()`

Comment: and what exactly are you storing in `Session["OtherProgramIDs"]`?

Comment: Your type is `List<Guid?>` not `List<Guid>`. You've made your GUID nullable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost there, first you need to map the Session object to `IEnumerable<System.Guid?>`, and then use `.ToString()` on each Guid.

```
var guids = Session["OtherProgramIDs"] as IEnumerable<System.Guid?>;
if (guids == null) return null;
var otherProgramList = guids.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

You may need to add an additional condition if the source list contains items that are `null`. E.g. like this:

```
var otherProgramList = guids.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Last but not least, the interface `IEnumerable<T>` is used very much by Linq, it enables the use of `.Select()` and `.Where()` (among many other Linq extension methods).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
var guids = (List<Guid>) Session["OtherProgramIDs"];
if (guids != null)
{
    var guidsStr = guids.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
}
```